# mongoDB custom query not working with symfony mongo client

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I m trying to get a result from MongoDB custom query via the use of mongo-client in Symfony.

Controller Code:

```
$query = "db.User.find({}).toArray()";
$client = new MongoClient("mongodb://ravi.d:1234@localhost:27017");
$db = $client->selectDB("Demo");
$result = $db->execute($query);
```

In my local machine, they give me a perfect result.
When I try in my server they give me an error as below:

```
{"ok":0,"errmsg":"not authorized on gsc to execute command { eval: \u0022db.User.find({\u0027name\u0027 : 85}).toArray()\u0022, args: [], $db: \u0022gsc\u0022, lsid: { id: UUID(\u00226777a092-3a1e-49c1-8eda-43365f1e018a\u0022) } }","code":13}
```

Please suggest me where is wrong I m

Comment: Can you share more details, like the content of `$_ENV['MONGODB_URL']`? Similar questions point out that you might have issue with permissions

Comment: Additionally, please add further details about your code - there is no "mongo-client" provided by Symfony

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase I just edited my question please check